# Cypress failing test due to CORS?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, iframe, cross-domain, cypress

I have a simple test that fails due to `CORS` and I'm unsure how to fix it:

```
    it("Visits home", () => {
        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
    });
```

This is the error:

```
  1) Test
       Visits the home page:
     SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `cypress.json` and add:

```js
chromeWebSecurity: false
```

Setting `chromeWebSecurity` to `false` in Chrome-based browsers allows you to do the following:

- Display insecure content
- Navigate to any superdomain without cross-origin errors
- Access cross-origin iframes that are embedded in your application

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it